# Generics declaration with wildcard character

Tags: java, generics

Is there any difference in below two?

Code:

```
List<? extends Object> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
List<?> ls1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: There's no difference, because implicitly *every* type extends Object

Answer (score 2):

```
List<? extends Object>
```

and

```
List<?>
```

Both are same. Because collections doen't allow primitives and only `Classes` ,in java every `Class` implicitly   extends `Object`.

You can see the difference If you write `List<? extends MyOwnParentClass>`.

But with `Object`, you won't get any extra benefit/loss here.